# Programmatically aligning items in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to position items inside my RelativeLayout so that the image appears first, the title to the right of it, and the content below the image area. Those three content items appear on top of each other. I understand that my LayoutParams probably aren't being set, but I'm not sure why or how to fix it. Any help? Thanks.

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.contentTable);
        for(int i=0;i<itemIndexes.size();i++)
        {
            RelativeLayout item = new RelativeLayout(this);
            item.setId(i);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(320, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            if(i>0)
            {
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,i-1);
            }
            item.setLayoutParams(lp);
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
                if(globals.myHitetItems.get(itemIndexes.get(i)).image!=-1)
                {
                        iv.setImageResource(globals.myHitetItems.get(itemIndexes.get(i)).image);
                    item.addView(iv);
                }
                else
                {
                    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimage);
                    item.addView(iv);
                }
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams text1lp =new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                text1lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,iv.getId());
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText(globals.myHitetItems.get(itemIndexes.get(i)).name);
                    tv.setTextSize(20);
                    tv.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
                    tv.setLayoutParams(text1lp);
                item.addView(tv);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams text2lp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                text2lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,iv.getId());
                tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText(globals.myHitetItems.get(itemIndexes.get(i)).content);
                    tv.setTextSize(20);
                    tv.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
                    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
                item.addView(tv);
            rl.addView(item);
        }
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure setId(0) is allowed. Also, rl.addView(item, lp); may work better

Answer (score 0):

That looks painful to debug.  It sounds like maybe the relative rules aren't being set or accepted.  I suggest simplifying to a static test set to verify that one row of views can be set relative to each other (and ensure that one of them is anchored to the layout itself).